# Rails 6.0.2.1: Finder results are not displaying in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a scaffold called patient and was trying to implement a search box.

In the controller, I added some simple search logic:

```
def index
  if params[:search_term].nil?
    @patients = Patient.all
  else
    @search_term = params[:search_term].chomp
    @patients = Patient.where("first_name LIKE ? ", '%' + @search_term + '%')
  end
end
```

The index.html.erb was not edited past what the generator made, but it always displays the retrieved data as if Patient.all was called. Yes, the false block is being executed. If I display the return of the .where() finder in the console, it outputs the right stuff.

I suspect that the view is not being updated. Or am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure `params[:search_term]` contains value you are expecting it should?

Comment: I assume so, based on the server log: 
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"XXXX==", "search_term"=>"john", "commit"=>"Search"}
FALSE
  Patient Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients" WHERE (first_name LIKE '%john%')
  ↳ app/controllers/patients_controller.rb:15:in `index'
Patient Length: 1

Comment: can you paste the logs from rendering index page

Comment: `Rendering patients/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered patients/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.2ms | Allocations: 438)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 19.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Allocations: 5623)`

Comment: please show the search form

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

I replaced `form_with` with a simple `form_tag`. (No idea why it worked though.)